# MATLAB: Taking Values from an Array to Display Images

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to create a program that displays the current board of an ongoing chess game. The board is given as an array where: 
**0 Empty,
1 White Pawn,
2 White Rook,
3 White Knight,
4 White Bishop,
5 White Queen,
6 White King,
7 Black Pawn,
8 Black Rook,
9 Black Knight,
10 Black Bishop,
11 Black Queen, and
12 Black King.** 
I was wondering how I could take these numbers that are given at a random location within the array and translate them to their given image files. Each piece has its own individual image file, and the board would be given as the background. I've already scaled the images down to the proper sizes, but I am not certain how I would place each image to its proper location on the board. How would I go about doing that?
For example, a black pawn is given as the image **'b_pawn.png'** and the chessboard is already created using **'checkerboard.m'**.

Answer (score 0):

You have already encoded the different pieces as numbers (0 for empty, 1 for white pawn, etc.). So all you need to do is to map these numbers to the corresponding image file. This can be done using cell arrays:

```
images = {
    'w_pawn.png' % MATLAB indexing starts at 1
    'w_rook.png'
    % ... fill in other filenames here
};
piece = board(i, j); % Get piece number at location i, j
                     % Update this to fit your code
if piece > 0
    % Field is not empty
    filename = images{piece};
    % ... display image here
else
    % Field is empty
    % ... clear field here
end
```